# LU Decomposition Trouble

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I'm having trouble decomposing a given matrix, A into its unit lower triangular matrix, L and upper triangular matrix, U.

After watching this, Prof. Kaw's video on the topic, my answer isn't making sense when I seek to return to by original matrix by [L] X [U]. (I checked this with MATLAB).

The matrix:

```
 9     7     1
 63    51     2
-63   -53     8
```

What I get:

U =

```
 9   7     1
 0   2    -5
 0   0    25
```

L =

```
 1     0     0
 7     1     0
 7     2     1
```

But this doesn't work, why?

Comment: You have to check the third row of your matrix $L$.

Comment: I really don't see my error. Wouldn't l21 = 7, l31 = 7 and l32 = 2?

Comment: The last row of $L$ has some sign errors. It should be $-7$ and $-2$.

Comment: Something is not adding up. Why does l31 and l32 have to be negative? When doing RREF, I multipled (+7) from row 1 to row 3. And then I multipled (-2) from row 2 to row 3. I thought signs didn't matter. But that's not the only problem, a33 is still wrong in returning my original number which was 8. Changing the 25 to 5 fixes this issue, but why? It doesn't add up?

Comment: Can anyone answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your $L$ should be $$ \begin {bmatrix}1&0&0\\7&1&0\\-7&-2&1\end {bmatrix}$$

and your $U$ should be     $$ \begin {bmatrix}9&7&1\\0&2&-5\\0&0&5\end {bmatrix}$$

Comment: I already got the answer, u didnt read my comment. I don't understand why the answer is that? Why are the signs on the 3rd row of the L negative? When I did Gaussian elimination, they weren't both negative? How do you determine the signs of the l21 l31 and l32 of the L matrix??